# When absolute position element's containing block is inline element

Tags: css, inline, css-position

I see the w3c writing

> In the case that the ancestor is an inline element, the containing
>   block is the bounding box around the padding boxes of the first and
>   the last inline boxes generated for that element. In CSS 2.1, if the
>   inline element is split across multiple lines, the containing block is
>   undefined.

I don't quite understand what's this mean, what's the diff from when the containing block is block element, Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

> the containing block is the bounding box around the padding boxes of
>   the first and the last inline boxes

in other words, width of the inline element will be equal to it's content, while width of the block level element will extend on available area (padding of ancestor reduces this area, see qoute from spec).

> Otherwise, the containing block is formed by the padding edge of the
>   ancestor.